# How to make a from= , to= argument work in Tikzcd in compatibility mode?

Tags: tikz-cd, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, cell, xymatrix

For some reason, which will probably be too much work to fix without breaking something else in my document, Tikzcd only works in my document in compatibility mode with the "Alternative syntax for arrows" which according to the manual was "used before the appearance of the quotes syntax for labels".

That means that code like:

```
\arrow[r, Rightarrow, "\phi"]
```

Doesn't work in my document, I would have to write this as:

```
 \arrow[Rightarrow]{r}{\phi}
```

To get the intended result.

How then do I write expressions such as `[from=A,to=B]`
as occurs in:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
   A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below, draw=red}]
   \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D, draw=red}]
   & B
   \arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

More specifically, I tried to make the following expression work:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathcal{C}
    \ar[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{r}{F}
    \ar[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{r}[swap]{G}
    \arrow[phantom,bend left=40, shift right=0.2ex, name=U]{r}
    \arrow[phantom,bend right=38.4, shift left=0.2ex, swap, name=D]{r}
    &   \mathcal{D}
    \arrow[Rightarrow]{from=U,to=D}{N}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

But the last arrow that was supposed to go from the middle of the upper arrow downwards to the middle of the lower arrow gives a error and is displyed wrongly as a tilted slightly upwards left pointing arrow. That is, the result that I get is:
[image]

When I would like something like:

[image]

but of course with other names being displayed.

Comment: The reason why the newer syntax does not work could be due to the fact that quotation marks are made active by some package such as `babel`. You could try placing `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after having loaded the `babel` and `tikz-cd` packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`tikz-cd` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf), apart from using node names that you can assign via the `alias` option inside the relevant cell (see second example below), you can also use the syntax `<row number>-<column number>` to denote the start and end of an arrow when using the `from` and `to` options (see frist example below). These options should be put inside the optional argument however. You can additionally shift the arrow using `xshift` or `yshift`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathcal{C}
    \arrow[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{r}{F}
    \arrow[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{r}[swap]{G}
    &  \mathcal{D}
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-2, to=1-1, yshift=0.5pt]{}{N}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    |[alias=R]| \mathcal{C}
    \arrow[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{r}{F}
    \arrow[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{r}[swap]{G}
    & |[alias=L]| \mathcal{D}
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=L, to=R, yshift=0.5pt]{}{N}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Both code snippets result in the same output:

[image]

---

Now, it is not too straight-forward to add a downwards arrow, because the two coordinates that depict the start and end of the arrow are not cells that can be selected via the above strategy. You could, however, extend the matrix a bit, like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & {} & \\
    \mathcal{O}(X)^{op}
    \arrow[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{rr}{\Lambda A}
    \arrow[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{rr}[swap]{\Lambda A'}
    &  & \textbf{Set} \\
    & {} & 
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-2, to=3-2, 
        shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt, xshift=-3.5pt]
        {}{\Lambda f}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could make use of the `start anchor` and `end anchor` options, but somehow the label of the lower bent arrow is placed wrongly in such a small size:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    |[alias=R]| \mathcal{O}(X)^{op}
    \arrow[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{r}{\Lambda A}
    \arrow[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{r}[swap]{\Lambda A'}
    & |[alias=L]| \textbf{Set}
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=L, to=L, 
        start anchor={[xshift=-1cm]north}, end anchor={[xshift=-1cm]south}]
        {}{\Lambda f}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The position of the labels can be fixed by adding a `\strut` to each cell to make them equally large:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    |[alias=R]| \mathcal{O}(X)^{op}\strut
    \arrow[bend left=47, pos=0.5]{r}{\Lambda A}
    \arrow[bend right=47, pos=0.5]{r}[swap]{\Lambda A'}
    & |[alias=L]| \textbf{Set}\strut
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=L, to=L, 
        start anchor={[xshift=-1cm]north}, end anchor={[xshift=-1cm]south}]
        {}{\Lambda f}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the problem comes from the document class that I am using and cannot change without having to change large swaths of my file. Thanks, although I agree that it is not "best practice", you could also agree that that first comment is not very reasonable considering that it talks about things which are not present in my question, showing that although the poster had time to complain it apparently did not have time to read, and one must ask themselves "to what end does one lose their time and that of others if they can't even make the time to read the question?" .

Comment: @FelipeDilho Well, I did not read the comments in detail. I just wanted to point to the reasons why people on this site (including myself) are sometimes a bit picky when it comes to MWEs. I hope that the above examples can help you, since I don't know anything about your document class.

Comment: That last comment is very optimal, thank you very much!!! I am sorry I sounded too grumpy, but Stack exchange seems to be attracting some people that get a perverted pleasure at closing perfectly reasonable questions for the sake of pedantry, which is rather toxic, instead of actually heping and getting help from others.

Comment: @FelipeDilho This is a site where many people come together. Being around here for quite some time, I can say that especially in the realm of Ti*k*Z and related packages, there obviously exists quite a number of people who just post some few lines of code, if at all, and seem to expect others to create full-blown diagrams for them. The toxicity of reactions against such questions (which sometimes may also affect other questions that are then to be regarded as false positives so to say) presumably stems from this fact.

Comment: Well this wasn't exactly my case, since I was asked to just "post some few lines of code" and not make a "supposedly" long question, that is a catch 22, if you put just "some lines of code" people will often close your question and if you take the time to write a sufficiently precise question people complain about your question being "too long" and threatening to close your question.

Comment: @FelipeDilho I understand your grumpiness. Just don't let it get you down. Your question is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a different route which lets you:

- work with your document, which can't handle the latest `tikz-cd` version
- while using the latest `tikz-cd` version

The approach is to separate requirements in space, i.e. THIS in one place, THAT in a different one:

- work with your main document, which uses the `incompatible documentclass`
- work with as many documents, representing one diagram each, based on the `standalone` class

---

Here we go:

**arrows.tex**, which is your posted code with a little twist. Just compile it, we'll come back to `arrows.pdf` in a minute.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
    %\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
   A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below, draw=red}]
   \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D, draw=red}]
   & B
   \arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]

---

**main.tex**, which uses an unusual documentclass, let's say `screenplay`: this mimicks differences, shortcomings, incompatibilities etc. your main class seems to have when it comes to cooperation with `tikz-cd`.

*screenplay may even work with tikz-cd, I didn't check. but let's pretend, it doesn't. as you see, it simply doesn' use any Tikz-dialect at all ...*

The relevant lines of code are:

```
...
\usepackage{graphicx}       % without tikz showing tikz-cd diagram
...
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{arrows}% i.e. arrows.pdf
...
```

[image: drama]

```
\documentclass{screenplay}[2012/06/30]  % just an alian class
\usepackage{graphicx}       % without tikz showing tikz-cd diagram

% ~~~ some shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\di[2]{\begin{dialogue}{#1}#2\end{dialogue}}
\newcommand\dia[3]{\begin{dialogue}[#2]{#1}#3\end{dialogue}}
\newcommand\newch[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\newcommand\pr[0]{Proggi}
\newcommand\ld[0]{Lad}

% ~~~ some redefine ~~~~~~~~~~~
\renewcommand\emph{***}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 \title{An arrows drama}
 \author{MS-SPO}
 \maketitle

 % ~~~ Characters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \newch{Proggi}, a programmer, full of energy.

 \newch{Lad}, a nice document creating language, with some bells and whistles.

 % ~~~ Let the drama begin ~~~~~~~~~~~
 \fadein

 \intslug[Night]{A stubborn documentclass}
 \pr{} spent already endless hours, while \ld{} keeps being stubborn.

 \dia{\pr}{impatient}{Why can't you just do what I'm telling you to do! Why can't you?}

 \dia{\ld}{amused}{You did read the manuals, did you?}

 \dia{\pr}{about to burst}{Yours, yeah \dots other ones?}

 \dia{\ld}{whispering}{Yes: about \emph{standalone} and \emph{graphicx} \dots There you go \dots}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{arrows}   % <<<
\end{center}


 \fadeout
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I was cosidering doing something like this as a last resort, but with the number of different diagrams that I needed this would make for a  unyielding and crumbly solution, needing to make  20 or so diagrams in different .tex files and then referencing the paths to 20 .pdf files. Jasper Habicht last solution is optimal for streamlining these diagrams in several differnt proofs in my file. One thing interests me in your approach, of course you included the .pdf with \includegraphics, but would you know if it is possible to link a .tex to be compiled together w/ main?

Comment: Fine. // For .tex files I know and use two options: a) `\input(somePart.tex)`, b) using package `subfiles`. With (a) you just have code, i.e. without specifying the documentclass: it's just "included", i.e. inserted as is. With (b) you can compile each somePart.tex on its own, **because** you basically specify the main documents class; counters of course will have strange values, but for control and development it's fine. ((b) won't work fr you) // Moving 20 diagrams outside doesn't sound like a big deal to me. E.g. `\includegraphics(a/gr1.pdf)`,  `\includegraphics(b/gr2)` will work just fine.